# similar face recognition using google cloud vision API in android studio

Tags: android, face-recognition, google-vision

i am trying to build an app in android which takes a an image (original image) and identify the face/faces in the image using google cloud vision API  and this is easy to do, then i want to insert a new image which also contain face/faces and compare between the original image and the new image, so i want to know if the new image has a face similar to the original image.
so can google cloud API  do this? it can identify faces, but can i use it to get similar faces to the identified face in other images? 
here is a simple code of how to detect faces

```
List<FaceAnnotation> faces = batchResponse.getResponses()
                                .get(0).getFaceAnnotations();

// Count faces
int numberOfFaces = faces.size();



// Display toast on UI thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```